# Minimum distance of a location; one table of points compared to a set of points SQL 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, spatial

I am trying to find the quickest way to find the minimum distance of one point to a table of points.  The only caveat is that the table of the points I'm trying to find the minimum distance of is 150K single points.

Or better explained Table A has 150K rows/points, Table B 1500 points.  I want to know for every row in Table A what is the minimum distance from all those listed in Table B.

I have a function that does the distance calc, as an added column to the Table A.  It just takes a VERY LONG time.  Table B has a spatial index.

This is what I have:

```
select a.*, 
       dbo.fxn_distance(geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + 
       CAST([Long] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST([Lat] AS 
       VARCHAR(20)) +    ')', 4326)) as DistAway
from Table A a
```

my function:

```
create function fxn_distance
(@pointTableA geography
)
returns float 
as 
begin

declare @distance float

select top 1 @distance = b.GeoLocation.STDistance(@pointTableA) 
from TableB b  
where geolocation.STDistance(@pointTableA) is not null
order by geolocation.STDistance(@pointTableA)

return @distance
end
```

Sorry if I am totally a newbie to this, and I know the solution is probably simple, but I just can't wrap my head around this.  So to hopefully clarify: I need to pass the lat/long of every point in Table A and see what the min distance is compared to every row in Table B, for every row in Table A.  I care what the actual distance away is, but not the actual point from Table B.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have better performance if you convert the function into a table-valued-function.

Here, I setup the test-bed:

```
USE tempdb;
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableA
(
    LAT DECIMAL(10,5)
    , LON DECIMAL(10,5)
);

CREATE TABLE TableB
(
    Geolocation GEOGRAPHY NOT NULL
);
GO
```

Here is the table-valued-function, which is basically your function except this returns a table.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fxn_distance
(
    @pointTableA GEOGRAPHY
)
returns table
as return 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 Distance = b.GeoLocation.STDistance(@pointTableA) 
    FROM TableB b  
    WHERE geolocation.STDistance(@pointTableA) IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY geolocation.STDistance(@pointTableA)
)
GO
```

Insert a simple test-row into each of the two tables:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TableA(LAT, LON)
VALUES (49.0,170.0);

INSERT INTO dbo.TableB(Geolocation)
VALUES (geography::STGeomFromText(
    'LINESTRING(-122.360 47.656, -122.343 47.656)', 4326)
);
```

The query that uses the inline TVF to determine the closest point:

```
SELECT a.*
    , d.Distance --This is the distance calculated by the TVF. 
FROM dbo.TableA a
CROSS APPLY dbo.fxn_distance(geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + 
       CAST(A.LON AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST(A.LAT AS 
       VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326)) d ;
```

Comment: how can I show the min distance as a column from the new function?

Comment: lol.. I guess that might be useful.  I've added that to my answer.

Comment: for the few rows that that I did try, it definitely seems to perform much better.  Question  Why is the TVF the better way to go for this?

Comment: The TVF evaluates the `Distance` once for each row in the source table, `TableA`, whereas running a regular function in the `select` clause can cause the function to be evaluated many times per row.

Comment: @user3347256 UDF scalar functions in SQL Server are notoriously slow.  Put "scalar udf performance" into your favorite search engine and you can find a plethora of information about it if the cliff notes version that Max just provided isn't enough to satisfy your curiosity.

Comment: @MaxVernon, what is the DistanceTable type for in this please? I can't see anything referencing it.

Comment: @MisterMagoo - hmmm... that's a really valid point.  It's absolutely not necessary for my example.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: The first version ran something in 2.5 hours vs the 36 hours it took before.  Thanks @MaxVernon!  In the updated version, is there any benefits to eliminating the user created type

Comment: @user3347256 - the user defined table type can be removed since it is not in use.  Leaving it there will probably cause confusion at some point in the future.